# when will a parameter in shader function been saved in constant buffer?

Tags: optimization, glsl, shader

Just wonder, if I have some paramters in a shader function, on vertex or fragment stage.

when will the compiler or hardware decide if it will be saved in local registers or optimize it into constant buffer?

let's say i have a function

```
float add( float a ) {     

    float b = 0.01f;     

    return a + b; 

}
```

I am quit sure the parameter b is in register and every vertex owns a copy of b

but if it changes to:

```
float add2( float a ) {     

    float sum = 0.0;     

    sum += a;     

    float b[256] = float[](1.0, 2.0, 3.0...);       

    for ( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ ) {         

        sum += b[i];     

    }     

    return sum; 

}
```

My question is, will the array in add2 (b[256]) be moved into constant buffer to save the registers for each vertex or pixel?

If will, then what kind of situation will this happen? does this optimization depends on Shader version? or hardware, or driver?